# How to use html file as div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to html and trying to make a website. So far, I've got an html file that has the header for my site and I would like to use it in all the pages I create for the site using jQuery's load function.

So basically what I want to do is load `Header.html` into `Page.html`.

This is the code in Page.html:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Header").load("Header.html");
            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Hi
    <div id="Header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Header.html looks something like this:

```
<div id="Header_Name">Adabelle Combrink</div>
<div id="Header_GameProgrammer">Game Programmer</div>
```

The only thing that comes up on the screen is "Hi" at the moment.

Comment: And it is not working? Any errors?

Comment: It's a pity to use JS to do that, you could simply use php

Comment: What if the user has JavaScript disabled? I would strongly discourage this approach.

Comment: Request the content of header.html through ajax then print it somewhere in the page.html

Comment: I think we can use `<iframe>` here. Can't we ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks good, apart from the backslashes in the src attributes should be forward slashes.

Is there any particular error you are getting?

Also, as has been pointed out, PHP would be better suited to this job.

`<?php include 'header.php'; ?>`

Aside from the accessibility question, there might also be a negative SEO impact.

**Edit:**

Assuming your path to jQuery is correct, then the code you posted should work (it does for me).

Things to try / be sure of:

- You are running this on a server (i.e. not just opening the file in your browser, as this will fall foul of the same origin policy). Check that the address in your address bar doesn't start with file://
- Make sure that the path to the jQuery library is correct
- Make sure that Page.html and Header.html are in the same folder
- Check your broswer's error console. [Instructions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: yes, its most likely the direction of the slashes. Nice Catch.

Comment: I've tried moving all the files into the same folder (so that no slashes would be needed), but it didn't help. So I doubt that the slashes are the problem (or atleast the only problem).

Comment: The guys is new to html and you want him diving into php? He hasn't ask for any php. He's not for off mastering the errors in his code. jquery is more than capable of providing the solution he needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `iframe` for including html file into the div.

Otherwise you have to follow some server side include method.

like, in php `<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine.
are you running the site on a web server, such as out of visual studio (iis express) ?
You can't run it locally. Ajax wont work that way.

Open your page in chrome, and press f12 to open up dev tools. 
go to the network tab.
do you see the ajax request being fired on the load function?

by the way, regarding  the header div,
a div is not a self-closing tag. Its a container. Its best that you close it using a closing tag.

Otherwise you might get unpredictable results in some browsers. ( I have not checked in a while, but it was that way a few years ago, probably in explorer 8)

Comment: I gave the div a closing tag, but it made no difference :/ When I open the network tab, the Header.html line is marked in red. It says OPTIONS under Method and "(failed) No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." under status. Do you know what the means?

Comment: this is useful information. It means your code is firing an ajax request, but there is a problem with the web server, you are getting null, probably because there is no web sever. How are you running this website, do you just have files in a folder and are clicking on the html file to open in browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing that that's not how you're supposed to do it. Is there a way of doing it from the files (I don't want to upload the website till it's done)?

Comment: you can run it from inside of visual studio. or you can use something like node.js. where you be publishing you site? wordpress/joomla?

Comment: THANK YOU! I had no idea that it wouldn't work from the folder. I edited the files in visual studio but I didn't realise I had to actually run the files from visual studio as well

Comment: I am happy to hear that this helped. The reason why running from visual studio fixes this is because it launches a local web server (called cassini) and is therefore able to respond to http requests such as jquery load. Notice that the URL is different when you run in visual studio as opposed to the file system. It will generate an IP address or show as localhost rather than file:c/...

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'header.html',
      type: 'get',
      success:function(data){
           jQuery('#header_container').html(data);
       }
  });
});

<div id="header_container">....</div>
```

The content returned by the request will go inside the header_container div

Answer (score 0):

Div elements require a closing div tag like so `<div></div>`.
there is no need to call small pieces of code from another js file, just write your code in the head element like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Hello</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Header").load("../Templates/Header.html");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't be afraid to ask for more info.

$.load() http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I added a closing tag to the div but it made no difference :( This is the first time I'm using javascript so I'm doing this a lot to learn how to have scripts in different files, the plan is to have more code in the file later.

Comment: Start small. work in the head element for now, when you get proficient   at java script and jquery. then you can minify your js into a file.

Comment: You should have the jquery script tag in the head element for a start. can you edit your code to show as it is now, so as I can see where we're going wrong please.

Comment: OK good! we are making progress. In the header.html file remove all the  html, header and body tags. they are not needed as they are already listed in the page.html. also Elements can only have individual id attributes. remove the div in header.html with the id equal to "Header".

Comment: remember to close out js code with a `;` eg: `$("#Header").load("index.html");`

Comment: youre not far off getting this code working, my testing revealed positive results. :)

Comment: I did what you said but I'm still not getting anything but Hi on the screen. When I open up the network tab (after pressing F12 in chrome) it marked "Header.html" in red. Could it have something to do with it not finding the file?

Comment: Yes that is an error, but it's a good one. We're getting close to a result. We just need to make sure the file we are loading, resides in the path and that the name matches the file. Please check for capitals letters and such in file paths and  file names as they are all relative and need to be exact.

Comment: Remember `../` in a path string represents an the upper directory to the file that called the path.

Comment: as user3164878 suggested change your backslashes to forward slashes.

Comment: I've moved all the files to same the directory, so I don't have any slashes anymore. I've also double checked the file paths and they all seem to be right (case sensitive and all) unless I'm seriously missing something.